# Not reload only header view in my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

is there a way to not reload the custom view in the header in my tableview?
Inside it I have a scrollview and when I return on the top of my tableview it change something in the layout, so I don't want reload it simply.

Thnaks

Comment: When I scroll my tableview I dpn't want to reload the header every time

Comment: I don't want call this method 
' - (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{ ' 
another time

Comment: If you don't want it - don't use it.

Comment: hhahahah... but for the first load of my tableview I need it

Comment: No, you don't need it. You can mimic that with your own view hierarchy fully controlling your view lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to don't `CREATE` your `UITableView` header's view in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` instead create it somewhere else like in `viewDidLoad` and only `return` it inside the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`. So it will not create and release always. It will get allocated and once you are done set it to `nil` or `release` it (depending on mode if arc or not).